# JavaScript: extract column headers from table configuration string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I need help grabbing some string operation in Javascript. I have a sample string as

```
var str = 'Supplier^supp^left^string*Spend (USD MM)^spend^right^number^5';
```

The string is basically a configuration for a portlet for two columns as Supplier and Spend..I have to get the column names from this string. Each star follows a new column config. In this case there are configs for only 2 columns and hence only 1 star exists in my string. Supposedly if there are  2 columns the string will look like

```
var str = 'Supplier (Name)^Supplier^left^string*Spend (USD MM)^Spend^right^number^5*Location (Area)^Loc^right^string^*Category ^Categ^right^string';
```

So from the above string i had written a logic to get the desired string as
after the 2nd caret i want 'Supplier'(1stcolumn data name and not 'Supplier (Name) which is a display name) ,(Moving to 2nd column after the star)after the 2nd caret 'Spend'.Similarly 'Loc' (3rd column) and 'Categ' (4th column). Can anybody help me achieve this? Here is what i had written

```
    function getColNamesfromConfig(str) {
        var i = str.indexOf('^');
        var tmpCatStr = str.slice(i + 1);
        var catField = tmpCatStr.slice(0, tmpCatStr.indexOf('^'));

        var j = tmpCatStr.indexOf('*');
        var tmpStr = tmpCatStr.slice((j + 1));
        var k = tmpStr.slice(tmpStr.indexOf('^') + 1);
        var valField = k.slice(0, k.indexOf('^'));
        return { categoryField: catField, valueField: valField };
    }
```

Comment: Also, please be careful with english; difficult-to-read means difficult-to-answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `split()`

```
str.split('*')[0].split('^')[1]
```

the above code will give you

```
Supplier
```

Check the following [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: I don't usually condone linking to W3Schools see http://w3fools.com/. However in this case it does at least give the basic information required for the OP.

Comment: Better reference: [MDN: Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Answer (score 0):

Or use a regular expression:

```
   function headers(s) {
      var re = /([^^]+)(?:[^*]+[*]?)?/g, names=[];
      while (match = re.exec(s)) {
        names.push(match[1]);
      }
      return names;
   }
```

Outputs 
    `["Supplier","Spend (USD MM)","Location (Area)","Category "]`
and 
    `["Supplier (Name)","Spend (USD MM)","Location (Area)","Category "]`
for your two examples

See this in action ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YjCn3/1/)).

Comment: tucuxi,I dont get your code..Thanks for the help but they give me the display name as Supplier","Spend (USD MM)","Location (Area)","Category. And what i required was Supplier,Spend,Loc,Categ..

Comment: then change the regular expression to exclude anything after the first space in the expression. For example: `re = /([^^ ]+)(?:[^*]+[*]?)?/g` (not the extra space after `^^`)